# Парсинг контактов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Необходимо настроить регулярное выражение, которое будет забирать только ссылку на контакты.
У меня есть выражение:

```
\"([^\"]*)\"(.*?)?\>(Kontakt)
```

и есть строка из которой мне нужно получить только последний "a href" (в разных ситуациях он может быть и не последним)

```
<a href="/" data-link-title="Start" class="cc-nav-current j-nav-current jmd-nav__link--current">Start</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2315645625" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/öffnungszeiten-schließzeiten/" data-link-title="Öffnungszeiten &amp; Schließzeiten">Öffnungszeiten &amp; Schließzeiten</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2316315025" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/flyer/" data-link-title="Flyer">Flyer</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2315732425" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/anfahrt/" data-link-title="Anfahrt">Anfahrt</a></li><li id="cc-nav-view-2315645825" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/" data-link-title="Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren">Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren</a>
```

С помощью данной регулярки получаю полностью строку от первых кавычек и до слова "Kontakt".
Что я делаю неправильно в настройке регулярного выражения?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это не совсем идеальный вариант:

```
`<a href="(\S+)"[^>]*>Kontakt.*<\/a>`
```

На предоставленном примере отрабатывает:

```
package main;

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func ExampleRegexp_Find() {
    str := `<a href="/" data-link-title="Start" class="cc-nav-current j-nav-current jmd-nav__link--current">Start</a></li>
    <li id="cc-nav-view-2315645625" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/öffnungszeiten-schließzeiten/" data-link-title="Öffnungszeiten &amp; Schließzeiten">Öffnungszeiten &amp; Schließzeiten</a></li>
    <li id="cc-nav-view-2316315025" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/flyer/" data-link-title="Flyer">Flyer</a></li>
    <li id="cc-nav-view-2315732425" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/anfahrt/" data-link-title="Anfahrt">Anfahrt</a></li>
    <li id="cc-nav-view-2315645825" class="jmd-nav__list-item-0"><a href="/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/" data-link-title="Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren">Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren</a>`;

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`<a href="(\S+)"[^>]*>Kontakt.*<\/a>`);

    result := re.FindAllSubmatch([]byte(str), -1);

    fmt.Printf("[0][0] : %q\n", result[0][0]); 
    fmt.Printf("[0][1] : %q\n", result[0][1]); 

    // [0][0] : "<a href=\"/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/\" data-link-title=\"Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren\">Kontakt / Termin verbeinaren</a>"
    // [0][1] : "/kontakt-termin-verbeinaren/"
}

func main() {
    ExampleRegexp_Find()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильное решение выглядит так

```
(.*)((<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"(.*?)?\>(Kontakte?)(.*)(\<\/a\>)))
```